# C#: Double Carriage Return Outputting when String only has one

Tags: c#, oracle, sqlplus, carriage-return

I have an odd issue that one would think is easy to solve.  Basically I am creating a string like this:

```
string temp = "SET pagesize 50000;" + Environment.NewLine + "SET linesize 120;" + Environment.NewLine + sQuery.Text + Environment.NewLine + resultsQuery;
```

sQuery is an update statement and reslults query is showing a breakdown of the the results.  Here is the results query.  The update query is similarly formatted.

```
resultsQuery = "SELECT project_no, contact_date, SUM(CASE WHEN control_group = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) \"CG = N\", SUM(CASE WHEN control_group = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) \"CG = Y\"" + "\r\n" +
                        "FROM OIC_TRACK_TEMP" + "\r\n" +
                        "WHERE job_no = " + tbJobNo.Text.Trim() + "\r\n" +
                        "AND cpm_customer_code = '" + lbClientID.Text.ToUpper() + "'" + "\r\n" +
                        "GROUP BY project_no, contact_date" + "\r\n" +
                        "ORDER BY contact_date, project_no;";
```

I then write the query to a command line:

```
updatessh.Write(temp);
```

The output in the command line looks like this:

```
SET pagesize 50000;

SET linesize 120;

UPDATE TABLE_NAME

SET PROJECT_NO = 'test'
.
.
```

How can I get rid of the double carriage returns in there?  Oracle pukes when it sees them.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the new lines?

Comment: now in the corresponding job_no field enter '0; Delete from OIC_TRACK_TEMP;' :)

Comment: Can't you just append it together with like `" "`? Also agree, this is a very scary thing to do in a production application.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, SQL engines look at both `\r` and `\n` as newlines, so when including them with Environment.Newline, or in Windows, `\r\n`, you are getting both of those.

Answer (score 2):

Try using \n instead of \r\n in your sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace doubled carriage returns with RegEx in final string, or just remove it before queries added.  But if you always has them - just remove (dont add) + Environment
NewLine